# Broker not available (loadMetadataForTopics) - kafka-node consumer

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-node

node for my nodejs code. I have an api for requeest/response.
First of all, I make a request `http://localhost:3000/number1` , after I start a consumer whitch consume messages from a kafka topic and from one partition "receive" and I try to find the message with id = `number1` . After I want to return a response to user with this value. So I create a consumer like the follow :

```
options = {
    kafkaHost: 'kafka:9092'
}
const client_node = new kafka_node.KafkaClient(options);

var Consumer = kafka_node.Consumer
var consumer_node = new Consumer(
  client_node,
  [
    { topic: 'receive.kafka.entities', partition: 0 , offset: 0}
  ],
  {
    autoCommit: false,
    fetchMaxWaitMs: 100,
    fromOffset: 'earliest' , 
    groupId: 'kafka-node-group',
    asyncPush: false,
   }
);


const read = (callback)=>{
            let ret = "1"
            consumer_node.on('message',async function (message) {
                var parse1 = JSON.parse(message.value)
                var parse2 = JSON.parse(parse1.payload)
                var id = parse2.fullDocument.id
                var lastOffset = message.highWaterOffset - 1
                //check if there is a query
               if(lastOffset <= message.offset || ret !== "1"){
                    return callback(ret)
                }
                else if(id === back2){
                    ret = parse2.fullDocument
                }
            }); 
 }

let error = {
   id: "The entity " + back2 + " not found "
 }

read((data)=>{
 consumer_node.close(true,function(message){
     if(data != "1"){
           res.status(200).send(data)
     }
     else{
           res.status(404).send(error)
     }
  })
})
```

If I try to make one continuous requests, after the first request I get a response :

```
{
    "message": "Broker not available (loadMetadataForTopics)"
}
```

my Docker-compose file1 is the following :

```
zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.1
      container_name: stellio-zookeeper
      ports:
        - 2181:2181
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      networks:
        - default
        - localnet

kafka:
      image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:latest
      container_name: kafka
      ports:
        - 9092:9092
        - 9101:9101
      environment:
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
        KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
        KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
        KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
        CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
        CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
        CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous' 
        KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081 
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper
      networks:
        - default
        - localnet
        - my-proxy-net-kafka

networks:
    default: # this network (app2)
        driver: bridge
    my-proxy-net-kafka:
        external:
            name: kafka_network
```

Docker-compose file2

```
app:
        container_name: docker-node
        hostname: docker-node
        restart: always
        build: .
        command: nodemon /usr/src/app/index.js
        networks:
            - default
            - proxynet-kafka
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app

networks:
    default:
        driver: bridge
    proxynet-kafka:
        name: kafka_network
```

Why that happens? Can you help me to fix this?

[ If you want more information feel free to ask me :) ]

Comment: You need to run your code in a container on the same network as the broker

Comment: I run a container on the same network..I will update my docker-container in this post, for see all my docker-compose file

Comment: You should put them in the same compose file, too. And just use one network to start with

Comment: I did that...I tried a lot of days to solve the problem but I cannot find the solution....after the first request, I get the same error                                                 
```                                               
{
    "message": "Broker not available (loadMetadataForTopics)"
}
 ```

Comment: Are you adding depends_on for the Kafka container? Does your code try to run before the Kafka server is actually healthy?

Comment: Well, the whole problem was that I changed the position of ``` options = {
    kafkaHost: 'kafka:9092'
}
const client_node = new kafka_node.KafkaClient(options);
```  in my code. I had put these line outside from the request, so in the second request I had this error. Sorry if I waste your time and thanks !!!